# Seeking a comprehensive discussion about multivalued exponentiation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Allow $\log : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be multivalued, by which I really mean that it's a relation $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. We can define $a^b = \exp(b \log a)$ without encountering any real problems (pun intended). This defines a relation $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, we're thinking of $a^b$ as being a set of complex numbers.

> **Request.** I'd like to see a comprehensive discussion of the structure of the set $a^b$ for different values of $a$ and $b$. Please make your answers as elementary as possible, so I can offer a link to this question to young people (e.g. 18-20 years of age) and have it be useful to them. Further discussion of the properties of $a^b$ highly appreciated, as long as it's elementary. No branch cuts please, except for brief digressions explaining why e.g. calculus with fully-multivalued $a^b$ is messy, that kind of thing.

*Remark.* This "maximally multivalued" version of $a^b$ appears in the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: This is not too broad. Asking for a detailed discussion is quite appropriate.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, thanks. The core of the question, which is describing the different structures of the set $a^b$, was intended to be pretty concrete and eminently answerable. The request to keep it elementary should hopefully make it more useful to a broader audience. And the other stuff I ask for is really optional, it's stuff that would give some extent and broaden the usefulness of the answer, but it's not actually necessary and an answer could be very useful even if it just focuses on the core question.